# If bagels are an Ashkenazi Jewish food, why didn't it reach South America with it's Jewish immigration?

Tags: food, ashkenazi

I've been to the US lately and discovered bagels, to find out later that it's considered a typical Jewish food.

I'm Ashkenazi myself and I've been living in the Jewish community of Buenos Aires my whole life and never had a bagel before. We have gefilte fish, kneidalach, knishs, farfalech, kreplach, pastrami, borscht, varenikes...

Why does this dish never reached South America?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because bagels are only "Jewish" because of the number of Jews in New York where bagels are very popular. All the other foods you mentioned seem to have come from Europe (maybe not pastrami).

Comment: What about Kugel (Yerushalmi?)?

Comment: @Shmuel we have that one too!

Comment: @ShmuelKoppel According to Wikipedia, it comes from Polish Jews in the 1600s.

Comment: on my first trip to Israel in 1974 I couldn't find a bagel to save my life.

Comment: You've never had a bagel!?